# Efficient fuzzy lookups in hash

Tags: data-structures, nlp, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I have a lot of data that needs fuzzily queried very quickly (which, of course, is relative, but within the magnitude of a few seconds for ~100 million keys, but ideally faster). It's in the form of key/value pairs, where keys are a unique string and values are an array of strings. This is the structure of the actual data, but I'm free to organize it into whatever data structures make lookup faster.

**A lookup of values for a key should include not only the values for that exact key, but also the values for all keys within a levenshtein distance within a predetermined threshold (say, 5).**

For example, a lookup of `hello` should not only return all values indexed under the key for `hello`, but also those for `Hello`, `hello!`, `yello`, `helo`, `hellooo`, etc.

The naive solution, of course, is iterating over each key, calculating its levenshtein distance, and including its values if it is within a certain threshold. However, this solution does not scale well with O(n) time complexity to iterate over each key, O(n-1) to iterate over each key to compare it to, and O(n) per levenshtein calculation, resulting in a lookup time of O(n * n * n-1) which, of course, is unacceptable.

How can I structure this data to optimize lookup time complexity? Space complexity, insert, delete, and edit runtimes are all irrelevant (though, I'd prefer to keep inserts under a second each to avoid bottlenecks there also).

Some information on the data:

- Unique keys are ready to be added at a fairly constant rate of 10/second
- Strings are ready to append to value arrays at a fairly constant rate of 10/second
- The size of each key's value is typically 1-5 elements, but some outliers have hundreds
- Each string in the value arrays are typically 20-40 characters in length

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845341/data-structure-for-retrieving-strings-that-are-close-by-levenshtein-distance

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/efficient-map-data-structure-supporting-approximate-lookup

Comment: Are you doing spell checking or something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58791875/140837

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the data structure being used here, but the easiest option might be to use ElasticSearch's [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) or its relatives. Well fundamentaly it is using an inverted index with good optimizations for executing fuzzy queries.